# wordpress loop – different html for every 2nd custom post

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

i am searching since a while for a solution to set my custom post loop like this:

first post> img left, content right // second post> content left, img right

this is my code so far:

```
<div class="container">
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'profile', 'posts_per_page' => 10 ) ); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); $i++; if(($i % 2) == 0) :  ?>

   <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(''); ?> role="article" itemscope itemprop="blogPost" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
                <div class="row centered wow fadeInUpBig" data-wow-duration="2s">   
                    <div class="col col-4">
                           <?php the_post_thumbnail(600); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-6">
                <section class="entry-content cf" itemprop="articleBody">
<span class="bold function"><?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'Funktion', '', ', ', '' ); ?></span> 
                       <h2 class="entry-title single-title" itemprop="headline" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                  <?php the_content();?>
                </section> 
                 </div>
                </div>
              </article>
<?php else : ?>

   <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(''); ?> role="article" itemscope itemprop="blogPost" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
                <div class="row centered wow fadeInUpBig" data-wow-duration="2s">  
                                <div class="col col-6">
                <section class="entry-content cf" itemprop="articleBody">
<span class="bold function"><?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'Funktion', '', ', ', '' ); ?></span> 
                       <h2 class="entry-title single-title" itemprop="headline" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                  <?php the_content();?>
                </section> 
                 </div>
                    <div class="col col-4">
                           <?php the_post_thumbnail(600); ?>
                </div>

                </div>
              </article>
<?php endif; endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
```

I know, this question has been asked a couple of times, and i tried already [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113185/how-to-get-a-different-html-for-odd-even-posts) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72348/alternating-post-layout) and i read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119041/wordpress-different-html-for-posts-within-loop) but nothing works for me. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: So what is your result right now? All are aligned left or all are aligned right?

Comment: the result is strange. there are 3 posts already added on this site, but i only get the entry-title, but its not giving the entry-title of the post, it generates the entry-title of the page (if that makes any sense).

Comment: i got this code (not altering) working already:

Answer (score 1):

I imagine its only outputting one post, and that post is actually the post content attached to the page. The problem is how you are initialising your additional loop within the page. You are creating a new post object - but you are not assigning it to the if / while statements:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); $i++; if(($i % 2) == 0) :  ?>
```

should be:

```
<?php if ($loop->have_posts()) : while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); $i++; if(($i % 2) == 0) :  ?>
```

Notice the addition of the $loop variable where you are setting your post object and arguments.

Comment: Hey Steve! That totally makes sense. It works now! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem :) Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

i got this code (not altering) working already:

```
                <div class="container">
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'profile', 'posts_per_page' => 10 ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
 <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(''); ?> role="article" itemscope itemprop="blogPost" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
                <div class="row centered wow fadeInUpBig" data-wow-duration="2s">   
                    <div class="col col-4">
                           <?php the_post_thumbnail(600); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-6">
                <section class="entry-content cf" itemprop="articleBody">
<span class="bold function"><?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'Funktion', '', ', ', '' ); ?></span> 
                       <h2 class="entry-title single-title" itemprop="headline" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                  <?php the_content();?>
                </section> 
                </div><!--.end col-->
                </div><!--.end row-->
              </article>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
                </div><!--.end container-->
```